# How to get string outside for loop PHP

Tags: php, loops, for-loop

How I can get `$lorem_text` as a new string `$lorem_outside_text` without changing `$lorem_text`?

```
for ($i = 0; $i <= 5; $i++) {
  $lorem_text = "lorem\n";
}

$lorem_outside_text = $lorem_text;

echo $lorem_outside_text;
```

Now result is: **lorem**

Result should be: **lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem**

Comment: What do you mean by `without changing $lorem_text`?

Comment: Do you want *both* variables to contain the text five times? It looks like that's what you've tried to do, but I'm not sure why you think copying a string would change the original.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With this piece of code you are **overwriting** your existing value every time.

```
for ($i = 0; $i <= 5; $i++) {
  $lorem_text = "lorem\n"; // this just overwrites $lorem_text value 6 times with same value
}
```

Instead try to concatenate it using `.` and also remove **extra** using of variables here `$lorem_outside_text`

```
$lorem_outside_text = ''; //intialize it as empty string
for ($i = 0; $i <= 5; $i++) {
  $lorem_outside_text .= "lorem\n";
}
echo $lorem_outside_text;
```

**Pretty Neat:**

```
<?php
echo str_repeat("lorem\n", 6);
?>
```

**DEMO:** https://3v4l.org/CIsCB

Answer (score 3):

You may use concatenating assignment operator, Please try the following code:

```
$lorem_text .= "lorem\n";
$lorem_outside_text = '';

for ($i = 0; $i <= 5; $i++) {
  $lorem_outside_text .= $lorem_text;
}

echo $lorem_outside_text;
```

Comment: Add details about what you changed

Answer (score 2):

You must append the text to the `$lorem_text`, not overwrite it. Type `.=` instead of `=`.

Personally, I'm usually adding text fragments to an array inside a loop, and then concatenate them using `implode("\n", $lorem_parts)`.

Answer (score 2):

Just use `str_repeat`, that will repeat the string however many times you want.

```
str_repeat($lorem_text, 5);
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to create an array in the loop that you later implode.

```
for ($i = 0; $i <= 5; $i++) {
  $lorem_text[] = "lorem";
}



echo implode("\n", $lorem_text);
```

Implode takes an array and uses the glue to make it string.